# Display a custom field above product price in Woocommerce single product pages

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, custom-fields, price

In Woocommerce I have set a custom field in backed edit product pages in a correct way… Now I am trying to display a product this custom field value, before product price into a single product pages.

But for some reason, with the code below I can get it displayed (and the product price neither):

```
function bd_rrp_price_html( $price, $product ) {

    echo get_post_meta( $post->ID, '_text_field', true );

}
add_filter( 'woocommerce_get_price_html', 'bd_rrp_price_html', 100, 2 );
```

Any help is appreciated

This is what I want visually to be displayed:

[image: showing the issue with image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Updated *(2 alternatives)*

Try instead the following revisited code:

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_get_price_html', 'custom_single_price_html', 100, 2 );
function custom_single_price_html( $price, $product ) {
    $custom_field = get_post_meta( $product->get_id(), '_text_field', true );
    if ( is_product() && ! empty($custom_field) )
        $price = '<span class="custom-textfield">' . $custom_field . '</span><br>' . $price;
    return $price;
}
```

Code goes in function.php file of your active child theme (or active theme). Tested and works.

---

Or alternatively you can also use the following:

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_single_product_summary', 'single_product_text_field', 8 );
function single_product_text_field() {
    global $product;

    $custom_field = get_post_meta( $product->get_id(), '_text_field', true );
    if ( ! empty($custom_field) )
        echo '<p class="custom-textfield">' . $custom_field . '</p>';
}
```

Code goes in function.php file of your active child theme (or active theme). Tested and works.

Comment: When insert this into Custom Functions my site goes down.. With this error:

`Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'product' (T_STRING) in `

Comment: @DorotiHenridgz I have updated the answer… the problem was in `is product()` and now it is `is_product()` as it should be… just a typo error… It should work now.

Comment: Hi @LoicTheAztec. First code worked, second one generated error on product page. But, seems like its not showing like it should be (my mistake). Its showing in format :
Product title
price
Weight

and should show in: 

Product title
Weight
Price

Can you revise one again, how to show in that format? Thanks

Comment: No, no i have a mistake. I need just to show above price. That s all.

Comment: @DorotiHenridgz Updated both… try it

Comment: First one code showed weight and price next one by one. Second code seems works. Thanks !

Comment: @DorotiHenridgz I have update the first one now and it works just as the 2nd snippet code…